# Finding inverse using logs

Tags: inverse

$$ x = \left(\frac{4^y}{-2}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}} $$
i have correct answer of $\:y=\log(4)-2x^3$
i'm lost on steps to obtain the answer. i tried the following:$$\log\:x=\log\left(\frac{4^y}{-2}\right)^{\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)}\implies\log\:x=\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)\log\left(\frac{4^y}{-2}\right)\implies \log\:x=\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)\left(\log 4^y-\log \left(-2\right)\right)$$ but was lost at that point.

Comment: original question has -2. you are correct and this is why i knew i was on the wrong path, but not sure how else to proceed

Comment: Is that definitely the correct answer. Since if you put $y=2$ into the top formula you get $x=2(-1)^\frac{1}{3}$ but if you then put that into your answer you get: $y=16+\ln(4) \neq 2$.

Comment: yes, book answer is above. i was also not sure how they picked base 4 except it was in the numerator of the original.

Comment: You could solve it using base-4 by writing as: $-2x^3=4^y$ then taking log to the base-4 of both sides giving: $\log_4(-2x^3)=y$. But that still the same answer as the one in my answer since: $\log_a(b)=\frac{\ln(b)}{\ln{(a)}}$.

Comment: how are you getting rid of the (1/3) exponent to make it look like you did?

Comment: cubed both sides, so $(x)^3=\left(\left(\frac{4^y}{-2}\right)^\frac{1}{3}\right)^3$ which is the same as: $ x^3= \left(\frac{4^y}{-2}\right)^1=\frac{4^y}{-2}$ then multiply both sides by $-2$ to get: $-2x^3=4^y$.

Comment: thanks bud, i see it clearly now! i was trying to follow my log do-undo steps but i failed to think about raising a power to a power. thanks for your time

Comment: No worries, happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

If your trying to solve for $x$ in the equation:
$$ x=\left( \frac{4^y}{-2}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}} $$
Then you could manipulate it to solve for $y$ but I'm not entirely sure this is accurate given the negative logarithms:
$$ \ln(x)=\frac{1}{3}\ln \left(\frac{4^y}{-2}\right)  \\
\ln(x^3)= \ln \left(\frac{4^y}{-2}\right)\\
x^3=\frac{4^y}{-2}
\\ -2x^3=4^y \\
\ln(-2x^3)=y\ln(4)\\
\therefore \;\; y=\frac{\ln(-2x^3)}{\ln(4)}
 $$